# ng-bind-html - with angular-sanitize - throws error in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to add html to a div as follows:

```
$scope.thehtml = $sce.trustAsHtml("<b>hello</b>")

<div ng-bind-html="thehtml">
</div>
```

**I see following error in console:**

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at htmlParser (js/angular/angular-sanitize.js:205:17)
    at $sanitize (js/angular/angular-sanitize.js:119:5)
    at Object.ngBindHtmlWatchAction [as fn] (js/angular/angular-sanitize.js:420:15)
    at h.$get.h.$digest (js/angular/angular.min-125.js:98:396)
```

The angular-sanitize.js:205:17 is this:

```
if ( html.indexOf("<!--") === 0 ) {
index = html.indexOf("-->");
```

Apparently html is not being treated as a String, therfore the error on indexOf ?

I have included the angular-sanitize.js, and added module 'ngSanitize' to the app.

Comment: Whatever `html` is in `angular-sanitize.js:205:17`, it doesn't have a `indexOf` function.

Comment: `$scope.thehtml` must be an html and must start with `<`, you cannot have it start with a text. What is `$scope.thehtml` ?

Comment: PSL> Updated the question to show that when we pass html string directly to trustAsHtml(...), same error persists.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/tkeNPDWdfrsRxAK68tH7).
From what I can see your implementation looks fine! My plunk is working and I am not getting an exception with the same code.
I have not had to add ngSanitize as a dependancy of the module, I have just injected $sce into my controller.

The versions of the libraries I have used are as follows:

```
https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js
https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-sanitize.js
```

Please try replacing your script references with these versions to see if it the libs that are at fault.

Let me know how you get on! Good luck :)

Comment: I have the same problem and it was that I was using an old version of angular-satinize.js when I replace it with the current one the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Include `angular` first, then `angular-sanitize`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.y.z/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.y.z/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```